# Using only one parameter of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm writing an app in Javascript, and while I'm comfortable with the language, I was wondering about unused parameters.

Say I have a function as follows:

```
function test(data, complete){
    if (data){
        return complete(null, 'yes');
    }
    else{
        return complete('error', null);
    }
}
```

I call that function with a callback, but am only interested in checking for an error - if the data exists, I can move forward with my program. Is it okay if I just pass the error parameter into the function?

```
test(data, function(err){
    if(err){
        //Uh Oh
    }
    else{
        //Keep going
    }
});
```

Or is it best if I pass both the error and the result (even though the result variable remains unused)?

```
test(data, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        //Uh Oh
    }
    else{
        //Keep going
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it okay if I just pass the error parameter into the function?

Yes. Arguments that don't receive an explicit value will receive `undefined` instead (but will still exist and be locally scoped so will still mask variables with the same name from a wider scope).

As an aside, any extra arguments will still be accessible through the array-like [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.

Function arguments are only used to create local variables.
You can pass any number of parameters to any function, no matter how its declared.

Comment: You pass arguments into a function not parameters ;)